# Is there a way to remove "put your phone into viewer" message?

Tags: android, google-cardboard, virtual-reality, google-vr

I'm struggling with Google VR SDK and in instance with `VrVideoView`. The devices on which my app is going to be installed will be for sure placed in landscape orientation and already in VR headset. For instant toggling the fullscreen stereo mode I'm using:

```
vrVideoView.setDisplayMode(VrWidgetView.DisplayMode.FULLSCREEN_STEREO);
```

But when the video starts playing, the message "Put your your phone into viewer" appears for a few seconds.

[image]
I don't need it as the device is already in position. Is there a way to remove it at all? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must call: `setDisplayMode` and `setTransitionViewEnabled`.

Set `setTransitionViewEnabled` as `false`.

Use like this:

`vrVideoView.setDisplayMode(VrWidgetView.DisplayMode.FULLSCREEN_STEREO);
vrVideoView.setTransitionViewEnabled(false);`

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue today. I am not sure but looks like; it's just the time limit issue when you are building the app for the first time and running on mobile device. You can try uninstalling the app and reinstalling it and wait for a while and then click back/cancel button. That's what worked for me.

Also, you are likely to face another issue after you solve this one, which is -  **https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/issues/144**

For this issue, set your screen orientation to "landscape left" and it should work.